# Is Ubuntu 19.04/19.10 compatible with maven 3?

Tags: maven, ubuntu-19.04

I have problem with my maven 3.6.1 and Ubuntu 19.10. I installed maven using: `sudo apt install maven`, and when i try to run my project using Intellij IDEA, the packages of maven libraries are not downloaded and when I run maven clean install i see:

Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.8.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org

This project works correctly on ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Somebody knows how to repair this?

Comment: I would guess that you have firewall or network issues.

Comment: Or a proxy you forgot to setup in your new settings.xml